# Excel 2013 Hangs when loading a number of Files

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, freeze, crash

I have 2 machines: Windows 7 with Office 2007, and a new Windows 8 desktop machine (6GB memory) with 8.1 and office 2013.
I have a large project with +- 70 Excel files. They are linked and need to be all open to update one another.
The "old" Windows 7 machine with Excel 2007 opens them quickly and correctly.
The new machine stops at about the 50th file and can't open any more, and hangs or crashes. It also loads the files considerably slower. Also this is a desktop version of Office 2013 but I think the machine "thinks" that it's an Office 365 setup. I have updated it with the newest version of Office 2013.
I've tried all the tips picked up online to improve the situation.(printer settings, com addins , eveything.) No improvement.
Did anyone had this issue ?

I've loaded the files in Excel 2013 in different orders to try and see if there is any pattern in the process.
During one or two file load sessions a notification came up to select a printer. This happened at about the 50th file when Excel is using +- 400mb of ram.
At this point Excel's ram usage jumps to 750mb and it hangs.
Online advice indicates that the (Default) printer is a problem with Excel 2013 and can be solved by setting the default to Microsoft XPS Document Printer.
I have tried this, and setting it to my standard printer, and the "Send to OneNote 2013" option. No change in the behaviour of the file loading process.
Changes in the file loading order do not alter the result. At about 50 files, when memory usage is about 400mb, memory usage jumps to 750mb and Excel hangs.

I could try and delete all the printers but I think Windows probably requires at least one to be installed.
I really think I am close to the key to the cause of the problem now.

Comment: Did you installed the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office? Although 750MBmemory usage is nothing to be honest.  There is some other cause.  Have you tried putting Office 2013 on the Windows 7 machine to see if it will work?

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. Its a 32 bit version of Office on a 64bit machine. At this point I don't want to mess up my excel on the Win 7 machine because then I won't be able to do this job or I will have a problem to solve first.

Comment: Are both versions 32-bit installations on 64-bit operating systems?

Comment: I cant get past your description of your "project": +- 70 Excel files that are all linked - phew!  I suggest you have gone way past the boundary of what is sensible using Excel in terms of complexity and fragility, let alone performance. You should probably migrate this to a database platform.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks Ramhound and Mike for your pertinent questions. It was suggested to me that I install the 64 bit version of office. I did, and the problem is SOLVED. My new machine loads all the files now. My old machine is 64 bit windows 7 with 32 bit office 2007. As I have said it deals with all the files, although it slows a bit towards the end. The new office 2013 (32 bit) obviously doesn't deal with memory as well as the older version. However, all is fixed (with the 64 bit office) on the new machine now. Thanks for everyone's efforts. I appreciate it.